# How to do power analysis in R for one-sample binomial test?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, simulation, statistical-power

I want to test the hypothesis that an event occurs significantly less often than in 7% of the cases:

H0: p = 0.07

H1: p < 0.07

I assume that the true proportion of the occurrence of the event is 3%. I want to calculate the sample size required to achieve 80% statistical power for a binomial test. To do this I have used the pwr.p.test function from the pwr package. This resulted in a sample size of 177 individuals.
I then run some simulations to check whether this results with the expected empirical power. I simulated 1000 experiments and calculated the percent significant p values. I repeated this 100 times to get a distribution of the empirical statistical power. It can be seen from the figure here that the distribution is not as expected as the mean of the distribution is too low: [Distribution of simulated power values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWhL.png)
Here is the reproducible code:

```
library(pwr)
set.seed(1234)
# function to simulate a binomial test
prop_pvals <- function(sample_size, p1, p2, alternative){
  successes <- rbinom(1, sample_size, p1) # simulate successes according to expected propability
  
  # get p value from binomial test
  p_vals <- binom.test(x = successes,
                       n = sample_size,
                       p=p2,
                       alternative = alternative)$p.value
  return(p_vals)
}

# function to get empirical power from simulations
get_power <- function(replications, sample_size, p1, p2,  alternative){
  sim_pvals <- replicate(n = replications, 
                         prop_pvals(sample_size, 
                                    p1, 
                                    p2, 
                                    alternative),
                         simplify = T)
  empirical_power <- sum(sim_pvals<0.05)/replications
  return(empirical_power)
}

p1 <- 0.03                                  # true expected proportion
p2 <- 0.07                                  # proportion to test against
power <- 0.8                                # statistical power
sig.level <- 0.05                           # significance level
alternative <- "less"                       # test alternative
replications <- 1000                        # number of simulations

# power analysis
pwr_res <- pwr.p.test(h = ES.h(p1, p2),
                  sig.level = sig.level,
                  power = power,
                  alternative = alternative)
# get sample size
sample_size <- ceiling(pwr_res$n)

# simulate empirical power from 1000 experiments 100 times
emp_power <- replicate(n = 100, 
                       get_power(replications, sample_size, p1, p2, alternative))

# plot distribution of empirical power
hist(emp_power*100, xlab = "Empirical power", main = "Distribution of statistical power")
```

It seems to be pretty clear that I am missing something here but I can't figure out what it is? Why is the resulting power lower than what I set it to be from the power analysis? I was under the impression that I was using the correct function to calculate the required sample size but could it be that I am wrong here? Or is there an error in how I simulate the data?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: By consistently returning values close to 0.8, this experiment (repeated 10,000 times) confirms the correctness of 177: `with(list(mu = 0.03, mu.alt = 0.07, alpha = 0.05, n = 177), (mean(sapply(rbinom(1e4, n, mu.alt), function(x) prop.test(x, n, mu, alternative = "greater")$p.value <= alpha))))` Using values of 176 and 178 in place of 177 gives noticeably worse results (consistently different from 0.8).

Comment: @whuber: why are you using `mu = 0.03` and `mu.alt = 0.07` that way round? I would have thought you want to use 0.03 to simulate values for the power calculation and 0.07 to test the null hypothesis.

Comment: I think you need a bigger sample to get that power. For example `pbinom(6,177,0.07)` gives 0.0322 while `pbinom(7,177,0.07)` gives 0.0668, so you would reject the null hypothesis of 0.07 if you saw 6 or fewer successes from a sample of 177.  Then  `pbinom(6,177,0.03)` gives 0.7172 which is rather less than 80%.  Or perhaps I have misunderstood. Doing something similar suggests sample sizes of 185, 186, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 221 or more may be needed

Comment: @Henry The *test* invokes the null hypothesis $\mu = 0.03$ while the power calculation requires generating data from the alternate hypothesis.  That, anyway, is how I have interpreted the (admittedly) confusing statement in the question.  Your interpretation sounds reasonable, too.  I settled on mine because its results agree with the sample size calculation.

Comment: Following the remark of Ben Bolker in SO, I recalculated the sample size using G*power (psychologie.hhu.de/arbeitsgruppen/…): "Test family=Exact" -> "Statistical test: Proportion: difference (binomial test, one sample case)". See here: imgur.com/a/1Df2SV4 The required sample size is 185 (which is greater than the value of 177 given by pwr.p.test) and the empirical power estimated with your code is now approximately 80%.

Comment: @whuber - I think getting the same power is a coincidence (and you do not quite get $80\%$ power, but $79.97\%).  My guess is that the real issue is that the functions applied use an arcsine transformation from the binomial distribution to an approximately normal distribution while ignoring the discreteness of a binomial distribution.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments and apologies about the confusion from the question. I should have explicitly stated the hypotheses and have done so in an edit. Hopefully it makes more sense now. From your comments I gather that the approach I have chosen here indeed underestimates the required sample size for what I want to do? If so is there a way to get more appropriate results using R?

Comment: @Henry Your comments about "not quite" really baffle me, because the original problem is to determine a sample size, which must be integral.  There are no choices lying between 177 and its neighbors 176 and 178.  Thus, it's unrealistic (and unproductive) to expect to find a sample size that achieves *exactly* 80% power.  In light of the edit your interpretation is the intended one--so just swap the roles of `mu` and `mu.alt` in my code!  This suggests the OP incorrectly switched these values in the original computation of sample size, that's all.

Comment: @whuber - my point was that you presumably want a sample size where the probability of a type I error is no more than $0.05$ and the probability of a type II error no more than $1-0.80=0.2$.  With a sample $177$ and $0.03$ as the null hypothesis and $0.07$ as the alternative hypothesis, you would just fail to get to $80\%$ power as the probability of a type II error is $0.2003$.

Comment: @whuber The 177 sample size came from the  `pwr.p.test` function but this was an arcsine approximation and gave `176.1211` (decidedly non integer) and it would have given the same sample size swapping the null and alternative hypothesis.  It turns out to be too low in both cases.